# How to pass a test if condition is True using Pytest

Tags: python, automation, logic, pytest

How can I properly pass a test if a condition is true?

Just a general example:

```
import pytest

def test_animal_color(color):
    
    fish_color = 'Blue'
    if fish_color == color:
        # pass the test and don't run anymore code

    rat_color = 'Gray'
    if rat_color == color:
        # pass the test and don't run anymore code

    frog_color = 'Green'
    if frog_color == color:
        # pass the test and don't run anymore code
```

The real usage for this will be used in a much more complex piece of code of course on which I will have methods inside methods and I want to pass the test when the parameter condition is met, it doesn't matter in which method, the test must pass and the remaining code should no longer run.

Comment: Unit tests don't end prematurely unless they fail. If you need to test all 3 things separately for some reason, write 3 test functions. Or check all 3 things in this one function every time. The `pytest` docs demostrate how to use `assert`.

Comment: Your question is straightforward but it's not quite specific enough and likely, more importantly, you would do well to at least skim through a few chapters of a good pytest book. I think you will find what you're looking for there.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `assert` with `any` to achieve that:

```
assert any(color == c for c in [fish_color, rat_color, frog_color])
```

`any` with generator expressions evaluates only up to first True value, so as soon as any condition is True any will also return True and the assertion will pass. If none are matching, False will be returned and `assert` will raise an `AssertionError`.